# Trouble mounting a folder from host onto my docker image

Tags: docker

I am trying to mount a folder from my host system to a docker container. I am aware of the `-v` attribute of docker commands.

My command is:

```
docker run -v /home/ubuntu/tools/files/:/root/report -i -t --entrypoint /bin/bash my_image -s
```

But this does not seem to work, no files appear at my designated container folder. This is very frustrating as I will need to add files to my docker image at periodic intervals so just adding them to the build file at creation wont cut it.

Comment: what is the error you are getting, if there is one ? have you check the folder permissions if its not the same user you are running docker cmd.

Comment: I am getting no error at all, I'm afraid. It just loads the docker image like usual except with no files being added to my specified directroy. As for folder permissions, the folder I created previously and has no specified permissions. ls -l on that folder returns 0.

Comment: what about user permissions? Maybe the user in your image has not enough right to see files in this shared folder.

Comment: The folder itself is owned by root and I am root.